# RegEx in Swift?

Tags: ios, regex, json, parsing, swift

I am learning Swift, and I have (another) question. Are there regular espressions in Swift, and, if so, how do I use them?

In my research, I found some conflicting information. [Apple Developer documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html) has something mentioning RegEx, but it looks so different than any other language i've seen. If this is the solution, how do I use it?

[This](http://benscheirman.com/2014/06/regex-in-swift/) website, on the other hand, suggests that RegEx doesn't exist in Swift. Is this correct?

In case it helps, I am trying to use regex to get the average price of a bitcoin from JSON-style API that contains the price, but also a lot of stuff I don't want.

Sorry for another basic question.

Comment: What is the name of the API?

Comment: Swift's RegEx support is very clumsy at the moment. It's still based on the NSRegularExpression class left over from the Objective-C days. You won't find anything as convenient as Python or even C#. I think Apple need to redesign the RegEx classes for easier use.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Unfortunately, Swift is lacking regex literals. But the external link you are referring to exposes 2 ways to use regex.

1. Make a class wrapper around NSRegularExpression and use this class.
2. Calling the Foundation method `rangeOfString:options:` with `RegularExpressionSearch` as option. This in Swift.

The 2nd way is cleaner and simpler to implement.

The method method definition in Swift

```
func rangeOfString(_ aString: String!,options mask: NSStringCompareOptions) -> NSRange
```

You can use it with regex matching as:

```
let myStringToBeMatched = "ThisIsMyString"
let myRegex = "ing$"
if let match = myStringToBeMatched.rangeOfString(myRegex, options: .RegularExpressionSearch){
    println("\(myStringToBeMatched) is matching!")
}
```

Here's Apple's documentation on [rangeOfString()](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:)

Comment: Nowadays, one apparently needs to use `match = myStringToBeMatched.range(of: myRegex, options: .regularExpression)`

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem. So, I wrote a small wrapper - https://gist.github.com/ningsuhen/dc6e589be7f5a41e7794. Add the Regex.swift file in your project and add "Foundation" framework if not already added. Once you do that, you can use the replace and match methods as follows.

```
"+91-999-929-5395".replace("[-\\s\\(\\)]", template: "") //replace with empty or remove
"+91-999-929-5395".match("[-\\s\\(\\)]") //simple match - returns only true or false, not the matched patterns.
```

Answer (score 1):

Another easy option is to use NSPredicate if what you're interesting in is pure validation (true/false):

Here's a quick Regex to match a Canadian Postal code:

```
func isCAZipValid(_ zip: String) -> Bool {
    return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "^([A-Z]\\d[A-Z])(\\s|-)?(\\d[A-Z]\\d)$")
             .evaluate(with: zip.uppercased())                
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Swift doesn't have regex so you will need to implement a wrapper class yourself or use some library like this which implements Regex class http://www.dollarswift.org/#regex