# iOS Swift - How to match a string that is "like" another string? i.e. "http" is like "http://"

Tags: ios, swift, string, substring, string-comparison

I created a URL Validation function that validates for URL as text is entered by a user into a text field.

However, in an effort to save performance and memory, I want to ignore entries that may contain common URL prefixes:

```
(i.e. http://, http://www, www, etc)
```

With that said, I want to be able to "smartly" ignore text that may MATCH one of these URL prefixes:

```
["http://www", "https://www", "www"]
i.e. If a user has typed "htt", it should be ignored since it is a substring of "http://www" or "https://www"
```

**What is the best way to check if a string may match provided prefixes but not necessarily are equal?**

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071444/regex-in-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. Had to use 'rangeOfString' function and check if user's text was in my control text.

**Code:**

```
    let prefixes = ["http://www.", "https://www.", "www."]
    for prefix in prefixes
    {
        if ((prefix.rangeOfString(urlString!, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil, locale: nil)) != nil){
            completion(success: false, urlString: nil, error: "Url String was prefix only")
            return
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

From the Swift Programming Language Guide, you can use the hasPrefix method.

Example:

```
if userString.hasPrefix("http") {
    // do something with userString
}
```

Source: [Swift Programming Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html)

Comment: That only matches the whole string. Doesn't match partial strings. I figured it out, see below answer.

Answer (score 0):

a simple partial comparison can be achieved by using `.contains`

```
let string = "hello Swift"
if string.contains("Swift") {
    print("exists")
}
```