# Compare a string by giving two possibilities for each character in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I need to compare a string by giving two possibilities for each character in the string in an (if) statement eg:

```
let str = "2 3 1 2"
if str == "(1||2) (2||3) (1||2) (1||2)" {
//Do Something
}
```

I know the code is not written correctly, but just to understand what I mean.

I used to use (Like Operator) in VB eg:

```
Dim s As String = "2 3 1 2"
If s Like "[1-2] [3-4] [2-3] [1-2]" Or s Like "[1-2] [1-2] [2-3] 2"  Then
//Do something
End If
```

I couldn't find anything similar in swift.

Please help, Thank you.

Comment: try RegEx ([NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009708))

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really know the difference between these sites, so I thought I could post here and there.

Comment: see [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773) (per my reading, your question is a very poor fit for Programmers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you describe is crying out to solved using [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Last time I looked, Swift did not support regular expressions, but it does allow use of `NSRegularExpression`. See ***[Regex in Swift](http://benscheirman.com/2014/06/regex-in-swift/)*** for an example of a Regex class.

So you'd end up writing something like

```
if Regex("[12] [23] [12] [12]").test("2 3 1 2") {
  println("matches pattern")
}
```

Another blog post on this topic is ***[Clean Regular Expressions In Swift](http://nomothetis.svbtle.com/clean-regular-expressions-using-conversions)***.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you are asking for is support for regular expressions. They don't exist directly in Swift (yet?). But you might want to have a look at [RegEx in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071444/regex-in-swift) and http://nomothetis.svbtle.com/clean-regular-expressions-using-conversions .

Comment: I see you posted well before me. I think we have doubled up because the question I answered was on [programmers.se].

Comment: No sweat. We came to the same conclusion. ;)