# Swift Regex Matching

Tags: regex, swift

***The pattern is not the issue***

I have a regex string

`var elementRegex = "([A-Z][a-z]?)(\\d*)?"`

I want to match that to text. Example would be matching it to `Al3Br3`, where I would expect the result to be

`Al`,`3` and `Br`,`3`

How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071444/regex-in-swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Swift specific question but more a Cocoa question. You don't specify wether you are developing for OS X or iOS but both have excellent regular expression support via `NSRegularExpression` and `NSString`.

Here is and example of their usage in Swift:

```
let s: NSString = "Al3Br3"
if let r = NSRegularExpression(pattern: "([A-Z][a-z]?)(\\d*)?", options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.allZeros, error: nil) {
    for match in r.matchesInString(s, options: NSMatchingOptions.allZeros, range: NSMakeRange(0, s.length)) as [NSTextCheckingResult] {
        println("Match:")
        for i in 0..<match.numberOfRanges {
            println("\(i): \(s.substringWithRange(match.rangeAtIndex(i)))")
        }
    }
}
```

This results in:

```
Match:
0: Al3
1: Al
2: 3
Match:
0: Br3
1: Br
2: 3
```