# Swift regex: does a string match a pattern?

Tags: ios, regex, string, swift

In Swift, what is a simple way to see if a string matches a pattern?

Pseudocode examples:

```
if string matches pattern ...

if string =~ pattern ...
```

(I have read the Swift docs and haven't seen a regex capability. I've read about adding a new `=~` operator which is a good idea yet more complex than I'd like because this is for a teaching project. I have tried `rangeOfString` but get the error: 'String' does not have a member 'rangeOfString'. I am looking for a Swift solution, i.e. not typing NSRegularExpression. I do not need to do anything with the match result data.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift Regex Matching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776945/swift-regex-matching)

Comment: @picciano Thanks for the link - I added a clarification that this question is different than the linked one because I want to use just Swift terms, not NSRegularExpression.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Swift version 3 solution:

```
if string.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil ...
```

Swift version 2 solution:

```
if string.rangeOfString(pattern, options: .RegularExpressionSearch) != nil ...
```

Example -- does this string contain two letter "o" characters?

```
"hello world".rangeOfString("o.*o", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) != nil
```

Note: If you get the error message `'String' does not have a member 'rangeOfString'`, then add this before: `import Foundation`. This is because
 Foundation provides the NSString methods that are automatically bridged to the Swift String class.

```
import Foundation
```

Thanks to Onno Eberhard for the Swift 3 update.

Comment: Why not use `regex.firstMatch(in: string, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.count)) != nil`? Isn't it semantically clearer than `range(of:options:range:locale:)`.

Answer (score 55):

The solutions mentioned above didn't work for me anymore, so I'm posting my solution here (I used an extension for String):

```
extension String {
    func matches(_ regex: String) -> Bool {
        return self.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
    }
}
```

Example:

```
if str.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]{1,30}$") {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Check out reference, examples and live demo of Regular Expression at: http://regexr.com

Comment: You saved my 4 hours. The reusable method was so helpful.

Answer (score 15):

To get the syntax you actually ask about, you can easily define a new operator which wraps the bridged `NSString` functionality:

```
infix operator =~ {}
func =~(string:String, regex:String) -> Bool {
    return string.rangeOfString(regex, options: .RegularExpressionSearch) != nil
}

"abcd" =~ "ab*cd"
"abcd" =~ "abcde+"
```

Comment: Thanks David. For this particular project I'm looking for a solution that doesn't define a new operator. (It would be great if Swift added your idea to the entire language, IMHO)

Answer (score -1):

In **Swift 4.2** the following doesn't return nil even if the string does not match the pattern:

```
string.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil)
```

As Xcode suggests:

> Comparing non-optional value of type 'NSRange' (aka '_NSRange') to nil
>   always returns true

Therefore what I ended up using is:

```
if string.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression)
        .location != NSNotFound {
    // do stuff if string matches regexp
}
```

Comment: You are calling that method on `NSString`, not on `String`, that's your problem. Your solution is technically correct for `NSString` but you can also just do `(string as String).range(of: ...) != nil`.