# How to check if a sentence contains a specific word?

Tags: swift, string

I'm not looking for how to find a string inside another string. I'm looking for a word. So the solution should pass these tests:

```
let result: Bool = senx.contains(word: "are")

let sen1 = "We are good." //true
let sen2 = "We care about you." //false
let sen3 = "are"  //true
let sen4 = "are."  //true
let sen5 = "Are."  //true
let sen6 = "I have a flare." //false
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: You are, in fact, looking for a string within a string, but with the added conditions of a) case insensitivity and b) without any surrounding letters.

Answer (score 4):

You need a regex with a word boundaries `\b` around the value you are checking the presence for:

```
let pattern = "(?i)\\bare\\b"
if string.rangeOfString(pattern, options: .RegularExpressionSearch) != nil ...
```

The `\bare\b` matches any `are` that is a whole word (not preceded nor followed with letters/digits/underscores. The `(?i)` flag ensures a case insensitive search. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0VdpgY/1).

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29784455/3832970) for the code to check if a pattern matches a string.

See [regular-expressions.info *Word boundaries*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) for more information on what `\b` word boundary does.

Comment: Just FYI: If you only want to match `Are` or `are` as whole words, but you do not want to detect `ARe` or `ARE` or `aRe`, etc. use *alternation*: `let pattern = "\\b(?:are|Are)\\b"`