# Search strings for certain words or prhases

Tags: string, swift, algorithm, search, optimization

I have over 1000 strings and a fixed array of [sub]strings. I'd like to know which of my strings contain any of the substrings. (Again, the substrings are constant.) I'd like to also make sure that words are matched, not the strings.

What's the most **efficient** way of doing this? Can I do better than doing 1000 times an indexOf() on all substrings?

```
let str1 = "During the winter holiday I'll go skiing."
let str2 = "Do knock on the door or chime the bell"    
let fixedSearchStrings = ["ring the", "chime the bell", "knock on the door", "knock on the window"]
str1.indexOf(fixedSearchStrings)   // returns nil. "During" is not the word "ring".
str2.indexOf(fixedSearchStrings)   // returns 2. "knock on the door" substring found, no need to check further in the sentence.
```

Comment: convert every string to a regular expression that will enable only spaces & interpunction before/after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this. The good of this solution is having fixedSearchStrings prepared you can buid the index only once and then effectively reuse it.

```
class Index
{
    var indexes: [String: Index]
    var terminated: Bool = false

    init() {
        indexes = [String: Index]()
    }

    func searchFor(keywords: [String]) -> String? {

        var ws = keywords
        if ws.count > 0 {

            let word = ws.removeFirst()
            if let i = indexes[word] {

                if i.terminated {
                    return word
                } else {

                    if let rval = i.searchFor(ws) {
                        return "\(word) \(rval)"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func add(words: [String]) {

        var ws = words
        if ws.count > 0 {
            let word = ws.removeFirst()
            var index: Index!
            if let i = indexes[word] {
                index = i
            } else {
                let i = Index()
                indexes[word] = i
                index = i
            }
            index.add(ws)
            index.terminated = ws.count == 0 || index.terminated
        }
    }
}

class SearchEngine {

    var index: Index!

    func buildIndex(keywords: [String]) {

        index = Index()
        for keyword in keywords {
            let words = keyword.characters.split(" ").map(String.init)
            index.add(words)
        }
    }

    func firstEntryIn(string: String) -> String? {

        var strArr = string.characters.split(" ").map(String.init)
        var rval: String?
        while strArr.count > 0 {

            if let r = index.searchFor(strArr) {
                rval = r
                break
            }
            strArr.removeFirst()
        }
        return rval
    }
}

let str1 = "During the winter holiday I'll go skiing."
let str2 = "Do knock on the door or chime the bell"
let fixedSearchStrings = ["ring the", "chime the bell", "knock on the door", "knock on the window"]

let se = SearchEngine()
se.buildIndex(fixedSearchStrings)
se.firstEntryIn(str1)
se.firstEntryIn(str2)
```

**RESULTS IN**

```
nil
"knock on the door"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func foundSubString(str:String,array:[String]) -> Bool {
        var count = 0
        repeat {
            print("count : \(count)")
            if str.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(array[count].lowercaseString) != nil {
                print("founded")
                return true
            }
            count += 1
        } while count < array.count
        return false
}
```

**Usage**:

```
let str1 = "During the winter holiday I'll go skiing."
let str2 = "Do knock on the door or chime the bell"
let fixedSearchStrings = ["ring the", "chime the bell", "knock on the door", "knock on the window"]
let exist: Bool = foundSubString(str2,array: fixedSearchStrings)
```

**Result**:

[image]

If you want to know more details about your search, for example, if you found a word and you need to know what is this word and his position:

```
func foundSubString2(str:String,array:[String]) -> (Bool,[(String,Int)]) {
        var count: Int = 0
        var matched = [(String,Int)]()

        repeat {
            if str.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(array[count].lowercaseString) != nil {
                matched.append((array[count],count))
            }
            count += 1
        } while count < array.count

        if matched.count>0 {
            return (true,matched)
        }
        return (false,[("",0)])
}
```

**Usage**:

```
let str1 = "During the winter holiday I'll go skiing."
let str2 = "Do knock on the door or chime the bell"
let fixedSearchStrings = ["ring the", "chime the bell", "knock on the door", "knock on the window", "knock on the door"]
let (exist,matched) = foundSubString2(str2,array: fixedSearchStrings)
if exist { print (matched) }
```

**Result**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions. It's going to be about 1000 times faster than indexOf or similar approaches. Internally regular expression will build a state machine that will be able to match all the string you want in one pass.

Comment: The regex pattern should look like `^| (ring the)|(chime the bell)|...|(last string to match) |$`. For how to use regular expressions see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776945/swift-regex-matching