# Swift regular expressions

Tags: regex, swift

I want to test user input to see if the entire input matches the following regex. How do I do that with Swift?

`[a-zA-Z]+@[a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: share your code snippet that you are trying, also make sure you write a swift code in `.swift` file... If you want to use Objective-C you should use a bridging header.

Comment: I just decided to make the question more general.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071444/regex-in-swift)

Comment: I can't comment on that one because I don't have enough rep. That solution works, but since I'm validating the entire user input, it matches even if only a small part of the user input contains it, even if the entire thing is invalid. I've tried using other options in the arugment.

Comment: Not related to your actual question (how to use a regex in swift), but please beware that your regex is very wrong for validating e-mail addresses. For starters, your use of an unescaped `.` matches *any* character, not just a dot. Another problem is that you don't allow e-mail to subdomains. Yet another problem is that you don't allow dots before the `@`. There are plenty of other problems too. If you want to use a regex at all, consider only making it a warning if validation fails, not an error, as a correct regex that allows all valid addresses is extremely difficult to write.

Comment: Yeah I know. I just threw it up for the purpose of this question. Haven't fine-tuned any of my regular expressions yet. I guess I could've just threw up a basic [a-z]. Not sure why I used a more complex one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look like you are trying to verify email addresses. Try this:

```
let test = "someone@somewhere.com"

do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-zA-Z]", options: [])
    if regex.firstMatchInString(test, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, test.utf16.count)) != nil {
        print("matched")
    } else {
        print("not matched")
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

`NSRegularExpression` is still carrying a lot of the ObjC legacy behind it so it's pretty verbose to use.

Comment: This works. Thanks! But what does setting options to [] mean? And how would I find out? I've tried Googling it, and looking at the Apple docs, but I can't find any information.

Comment: `[]` is an empty set. `options: []` means "no option". It's equivalent to `options: nil` in ObjC. Check the documentation. If the `option` parameter conforms to `OptionSetType`, you can use a step instead of bitwise `or`. Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_OptionSetType_Protocol/

Comment: Actually, if I'm trying to validate the entire user input, it will match "a@gmail.com", but will also match "sometext a@gmail.com" Does the regex need to be refined, or is there a different option I should be using?

Comment: This regular expression is wrong to validate an email address. It does not allow numbers, the range for the username is wrong (should be capital Z) and the dot should have been escaped (now it means any character, you really want to match for a dot). Try this instead: "[a-zA-Z\\d_]+@[a-zA-Z\\d_]+\\.[a-zA-Z\\d_]+" (not perfect, just better.)

Comment: @pizzamonster thanks. Didn't realize I had these mistake all this time

Comment: As it is Foundation stuff should the range be to test.utf16.count?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to do it in Swift *without* `NSRegularExpression`. You still need to `import Foundation`.

```swift
let email = "foo@bar.com"
if let _ = email.range(of: #"[a-zA-Z]+@[a-zA-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]"#,
                                 options: .regularExpression) {
    print("We have a match!")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this extension in all of my projects:

```
extension String {
    func matchsIn(regexString: String) -> Bool {
        do { let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regexString, options: [])
             return regex.firstMatch(in: self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, self.utf8.count)) != nil
        } catch { return false }
    }
}
```